# correct routing for multiple devices

Tags: linux, networking, routing, debian

I have Debian Lenny machine with 3 interfaces enabled (eth0-2), and I have problems as follow.

- eth1 is connected to a router and this router has portforwarding for port80.
- eth2 is connected direct to the internet

If I open a website hosted on my system via the router it works fine.  If I try to open the same via the eth2 connetion it does not!

`tshark` shows incomming trafic on eth2 but nothing goes out there.

`iptabes` accepts all

My routing table:

```
Ziel            Router          Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
10.9.0.2        *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
212.236.24.128  *               255.255.255.224 U     0      0        0 eth2
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
192.168.0.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
10.9.0.0        10.9.0.2        255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tun0
default         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth1
default         212.236.024.129 0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth2
default         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
```

Comment: You cannot use multiple default gateways on a server. The simplest fix would be to put your internet connection on the router and design your network so everything is defaulted through the router.

Comment: i need the network configuration like it is<br>
for outgoing internet it takes the route via my router thats ok<br>
but for incoming it shouldt answer on the same interface where the incomming accepts<br>
i know that 3 default routes are wrong but how can i solve that problem

Comment: You can solve the problem by removing two of the three defaults.  That sounds like a snarky answer, but it is the best anyone can give unless you give us more information or change your mind about leaving the network configuration as it is

Comment: 1.) what i need is following. access from outside via my router<br>
2.) also access from outside direct to the server via eth2 and thats the problem direct access via eth2 wil not responded on the same interface<br>
now i removed all default routes except those of eth1 but nothing changed in the behaver

Comment: Then look up how to do port forwarding and NAT on your router

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting bind9 to answer on a Dual NIC machine?](http://serverfault.com/questions/374192/getting-bind9-to-answer-on-a-dual-nic-machine)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use multiple default gateways on a server. The simplest fix would be to put your internet connection on the router and design your network so everything is defaulted through the router.  You will need to configure NAT / port forwarding to make this work as you hope for.